# Obtain date from timestamp

Tags: hiveql, hue

I have a date field like this: 2017-03-22 11:09:55 (column name: install_date)
I have another date field with date like this: 2017-04-20 (column name: test_date)

I would like to obtain only the date field from the above (2017-03-22) so that I can perform a DATEDIFF between install_date and test_date.

Comment: did you happen to try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for this in `Hive`, you can use `TO_DATE` function.

```
TO_DATE('2000-01-01 10:20:30') returns '2000-01-01'
```

`NOTE`: Input to TO_DATE is a string

Comment: Input to TO_DATE can be also a Timestamp.