# year, month and date from timestamp column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to extract the year, month and day part of a timestamp column in hive.

At present the output looks like 2016-05-20 01:08:48. I want it to output only the 2016-05-20 part. I have tried using `SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date,'yyyy-mm-dd')) FROM ANS.test` but it hasn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain date from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291975/obtain-date-from-timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the to_date function:

```
select to_date(date_column) 
from ANS.test
```

To get the year, month or day you can use the `YEAR(date_column)`, `MONTH(date_column)` and `DAY(date_column)` functions

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you:
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-05-20 01:08:48', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 'yyyy-mm-dd');

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please use code formatting so it is more readable